# iOS Detect Flash Content in UIWebView

Tags: javascript, ios, flash, uiwebview, swfobject

I need to detect if there is a flash object contained in a page in UIWebView instance. I have checked out the [SWFObject library](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) and checked out the [JavaScript API](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/api) in particular, but don't see any methods that would provide me with a boolean value based on if a flash object is present in the page. Is there something I am missing, or is there an alternate way to do this?